# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native

////////////this is homescreen, here i try to go to 'Components'. it's not recognize 'props.navigation.navigate

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Hi there !</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Components')}
          title="Go to Componetes demo"
        />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

/////////This is the index.js here i am using homescreen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,View } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import ListScreen from './src/screens/ListScreen';
import ComponentsScreen from './src/screens/ComponentsScreen';
import Header from './src/screens/Header';

const App = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Header headerText={'Hello ! '}/>
      <HomeScreen />
    </View>
  );
};




AppRegistry.registerComponent('Tal', () => App);
```

This is the App.js,and the navigator is here. This is edited.
i Need help .///////////////////////////////////////////////

/////##########//////////

```
 /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {  createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const navigator = createStackNavigator (
{
  Home : HomeScreen,
  Components : ComponentsScreen,
  List : ListScreen
},
{
  initialRouteName : 'Home',
  defaultNavigationoptions :  {
    title : App
  }
}
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you use HomeScreen?

Comment: Edit your main question, it's unreadable from comments

Comment: Is this you App.js? where is the navigator?

Comment: Pass `navigation={this.props.navigation}` in your `HomeScreen` component. For example : `<HomeScreen navigation={this.props.navigation} />`. Otherwise declare your component as Class component.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand how are you gonna have that `navigation` as prop inside a component.

Each `screen` component in your app is provided with the navigation prop automatically. It's important to highlight the *navigation* prop is not passed into *all* components; only *screen* components receive this prop automatically! *React Navigation* doesn't do anything magic here. For example, if you were to define a `MyBackButton` component and render it as a child of a screen component, you would not be able to access the *navigation* prop on it. If, however, you wish to access the navigation prop in any of your components, you may use the [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html) HOC.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the navigation prop from the screen where you are introducing the `homeScreen`. It does not have access of navigation that is why it is throwing the error.

Comment: Try retreving the navigation by printing it in log. IF the navigation is passed this stuff has to work

Comment: i tryed it...not recognize

Comment: That's what exactly I said. You're not passing the navigation correctly. You've to pass the navigation for it to navigate from the parent screen